# Assinging multiple users to a task in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there any way that a can assign multiple people or a group to a task item in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not now. This feature is registered and under review: [Assign a Work Item to Multiple People](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/assign-a-work-item-to-multiple-people/385104)

As a workaround, you can copy your task ([Copy or clone a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#copy-or-clone-a-work-item)) and assign it to an additional user.